# asp.net core headers caching issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Here are the request headers from postman to my asp.net_core 2.0 API.

- Content-Type: application/json
- **Accept: application/json**

Response from my asp.net core application is an exception thrown in a string format.
But the below response headers have been sent from the API to postman.

Cache-Control : no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma : no-cache
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
**Content-Type : application/json**; charset=utf-8
Age : 0
Server : Kestrel

Since the Request body is a string , and the Content-Type is set as application/json. Client is unable to parse it.
I have added the below code in my API middleware startup class configure() method to disable Headers cache. But since the "Accept" header is application/json, the response header "content-type" is also set to application/json instead of text/plain .
Please let me know what additional things have to be done to change the response header content-type to text/plain.

```
app.Use(
    next =>
    {
        return async context =>
        {
            context.Response.OnStarting(
            () =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, 
                must-revalidate");
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Age", "0");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
            await next(context);
        };
    });
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Why not set the content type properly in your code if it needs to be something specific? I don’t see how this is related to caching in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sami-kuhmonen. 

If the "Accept" header is removed or modified to include text/plain like

Accept: application/json;text/plain 

then the response Content type is text/plain . 

Is there any solution to set response content-Type independent of Request's Accept header.

Comment: Please add code of your controller that causes exception.