# How to set cache control

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I set cache control to no store and pragma to no cache?

Currently I get this error when I run my application:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Internal.IResponseCachingPolicyProvider'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.ResponseCachingMiddleware'.

This is my startup.cs

```
app.UseResponseCaching();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
        new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            NoStore = true,
            NoCache = true,
        };

    await next();
});
```

What else do I need to set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you already registered in your [ConfigureService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-2.2) like this ?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddResponseCaching();
    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseResponseCaching();

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl = 
            new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
            {
                Public = true,
                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
            };
        context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] = 
            new string[] { "Accept-Encoding" };

        await next();
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Update you can find how to set pragma with this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898603/asp-net-core-headers-caching-issue)

Comment: Ah! I missed that. Thanks! Also, is no cache and no store correct? How can I set the Pragma as well?